# dynamic sql UPDATE query

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I update a table in the data base where the SET clause from MySQL query depends on variables?  It can be one $var, two, or many more.

Here is my ex. code:

```
$name = 'comp_name = "'.$nume.'",';
$large = 'logolarge = "'.$linklogolarge.'",';  
$small = 'logosmall = "'.$linklogosmall.'",';

...............................

 $sql = 'UPDATE company
    SET
            '.$name.'
            '.$large.'
            '.$small.'
    WHERE id_comp = 43 ';
```

The problem is that the normal syntax of the UPDATE query is that after SET .......between values needs a comma " , "

ex.

```
    UPDATE table 
     SET 
     col1 = x , 
     col2 = y , 
     col3 = z 
     WHERE id = 4
```

and at the end before WHERE doesn't needs one ..... ( ex. after " z ")

So how can I make the sql query to accept different combination of those $var ...( only '.$name.' or '.$name.' and '.$large.' or only last two '.$large.' and '.$small.' .... etc)

basically any combination between those 3 var ...and maybe combining more than 3 var.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you're asking. Possible to clarify? You may want to check out [mysql's `update` syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
$name = "comp_name = '$nume'";
$large = "logolarge = '$linklogolarge'";  
$small = "logosmall = '$linklogosmall'";

$sql = "UPDATE company SET " . $name;
if( ! is_null( $linklogolarge ) ) $sql = $sql . ", " . $large;
if( ! is_null( $linklogosmall ) ) $sql = $sql . ", " . $small;

$where = " WHERE id_comp = 43"; /* change this if required*/
$sql = $sql . $where;

echo $sql;
```

Comment: thanks for the help ... but this method only works if you have $name not NULL all the time ...I was looking for a code to allow any kind of combination ...and maybe with more than 3 $var

Comment: It is only a manual process. Possible way is as what I suggested. And, define a `boolean` to check if at least one column value is set. If false, don't execute query.